# Core Audio SDK, Xcode 5.1

Tags: xcode, audio, plugins, core-audio, xcode5.1

I've been trying to figure out how to implement Core Audio development kit into the current version of Xcode but have had no luck. I can't find where to download the SDK or where it would be located inside Xcode. The tutorial that apple offers only brings you to their website which doesn't have it, they have audio tools and examples but no SDK. Am I missing something? I have been searching my computer to see where any of the source files would be but have had no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to download anything actually, it comes with XCode.

Import the CoreAudio header where you need it with

```
#import <CoreAudio/CoreAudio.h>
```

Then head over to your targets build phases to section "Link Binary With Libraries".

[image]

There you need to add CoreAudio and you are done with it.

[image]

In case you are new to CoreAudio I can highly recommend the book ["Learning Core Audio"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321636848). It helped me a ton.

Comment: Awesome! How simplistic! I will definitely check out the book. Thanks for your help. I was just really thrown because the tutorial states to download it and I know I saw a lot of posts saying that it was included. I then tried to find the folders with the files in it and had no luck.